# How to tell what is causing Internet Explorer to give security warning

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, security

Does anybody have tips on how to tell what is causing Internet Explorer to give a security warning for some flash videos on my site? I've looked through the HTML and can't find anything, so it appears to be somewhere in the Flash itself. But I'm not really sure.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the text of the warning? Also, are you using a self signed SSL cert? If not, is your cert expired?

Comment: It's not the cert because it's ok on other pages. The warning is "Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?
This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise security of the entire webpage."

There's an option for "More Info" but it just pulls up a generic help, it doesn't tell me what IE thinks is the problem.

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is _still_ some content being loaded via `http`. I know you've said in your comments on my answer that all requests are made over `https`, but you must have missed something. Go back and check all the referenced content again.

Answer (score 5):

This is generally caused by a page that is loaded via `https` but references content via `http`. Make sure *all* content on the page loads with `https`. That includes all images, flash movies, css, javascript, etc.

A vastly underutilized feature of html that helps avoid this kind of thing is support for relative schemes on absolute urls. The way it works is something like this: Instead of:

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

do this:

```
<img src="//example.com/images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
```

The second example will load the image with the same scheme as the containing page was loaded. Browser support for this feature is excellent. An example of a large site that leverages this feature heavily is [SlashDot.org](http://slashdot.org/). View source on their homepage and you'll see many uses for all their CDN content.

Comment: All of the HTML is either using https or a relative path. I've fixed that problem before. This time there's something else. I wish IE would tell me what it is!

Comment: What version of IE? Are you able to post some HTML in your question? Is there any AJAX happening? Do you have ads on the page? Is the flash movie dynamically loading content?

Comment: It's IE8. I'm running a monitor of all the requests and they are all https.

Comment: Make sure your cache is cleared before running the monitor. If a resource that was originally loaded via `http` is getting pulled out of a browser cache, it might trigger the warning without showing up on your monitor.